# How to align inputs in bootstrap form with input-group-addons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have a very simple form with Bootstrap 3 which I can easily (automatically) align when I don't use `input-group-addon`s.

After I use them in my form it is impossible to align it (the line with addons is wider because of added addons)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="product_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" placeholder="Product name">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="product_price" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control bfh-number" id="product_price" placeholder="Price" data-min="0" data-max="9999999">
        <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="product_description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="product_description" placeholder="Description" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yzxy3/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Bootstrap documentation for input groups says :

> **Don't mix input-group with other components.** (see:http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)
>
> Do not mix form groups or grid column classes directly with input groups. Instead, nest the input group inside of the form group or grid-related element."

So you can't mix "col-sm-4" with "input-group" in the same class. You have to create 2 div class, the first with "col-sm-4" and the other with "input-group"

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control bfh-number" id="product_price" placeholder="Price" data-min="0" data-max="9999999">
    <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yzxy3/181/)**

Answer (score 17):

It's because `.input-group` has default

```
padding-right: 0;
padding-left: 0;
```

so your `div` will stretch to the full width, where as `.col-sm-4` has default styles as:

```
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

So to make it work as expected, you can add this style:

```
.input-group[class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yzxy3/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

I find that I needed to include: float: left as well. So, the css is:

```
.input-group[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

If not, my multi-column rows broke when I upgraded from v3.0.2 to v3.0.3.

--cp

Answer (score 0):

.input-group[class*="col-"] is not useful if you use

```
<fieldset>
```

**Here is solution!**

```
.makeHorizontal{  
float:left;
padding-left:20px;
}
```